# Html titles font-weight changes using google map API

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

Something weird happens when I use google map API. When I include a map in a page, title's font-weight visualy changes alone. When I'm looking at the console, nothing changes the same font-weight is used but the visual result is clearly not the same.

Here the code i'm using with the map :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>wtf
    </title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />

    <!--My CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')?>"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/main.css')?>"/>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <section id="sectionContact" class="content">
        <div class="title"><h1>Contact</h1></div>
        <div class="coordonnees">
            <h3>Address :</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>

                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>

                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.1</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
            <p>Chargement de la carte</p>
        </div>
        <div class="situation">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.:</h3>
            <p>
                Le cabinet est situé en plein centre de la Ville de MULHOUSE, dans le prolongement du bâtiment où est établi la CPAM de MULHOUSE, en face du Tribunal de Grande Instance de MULHOUSE.
            </p>

            <h3>houston:</h3>
            <p>
                or sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla erat ipsum, dictum nec sodales sit amet, hendrerit sit amet urna. Nullam lobortis at elit ut auctor. Aenean lobortis pretium velit at scelerisque. Sed in libero vel ante vulputate congue eget non augue. Donec consectetur risus i
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=SECRET"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var initialize;
        initialize = function(){
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7514108, 9.341490199999953); // Correspond au coordonnées du cabinet
            var myOptions = {
                zoom      : 14,
                center    : latLng,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, // Type de carte, différentes valeurs possible HYBRID, ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN
                maxZoom   : 20
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : latLng,
                map      : map,
                title    : "Cabinet"
                //icon     : "marker_lille.gif" // Chemin de l'image du marqueur pour surcharger celui par défaut
            });
        };
        initialize();
    </script>
</div><!--Fin div id wrapper (menu.php)-->
</div><!--Fin div id content (header.php)-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jQuery/dist/jquery.min.js') ;?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/main.js') ;?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is that your CSS sets `font-weight:100;`, but your Google font call doesn't include the `100` weight: `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700`.  When you load the page without Google Maps, the font appears thicker than you specify because it can't display the thin version if you didn't call it.

The reason Google Maps changes the weight is that it includes the full Roboto font (i.e. including the 100 weight).  So when Maps is on the page, the font can display correctly at the specified weight.  That's why it looks thin with Maps (as you specify) and thick without.

Add 100 to the list of weights you want to download and the problem should be fixed:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700">
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem @Aurélien!  If you find an answer helpful (not just mine), you can up-vote it, and if one solved your problem, you can mark it as solved so other people can tell the question has an answer.

Comment: I did it but it seems that my low reputation won't affect the post score as mentionned when i click on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's font issue.
for With-Map page font is included in the `<head>`
but in the without map page it is not included.